# Conditionnal close tags ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this kind of json response :

```
{id: 1, name: a}
{id: 2, name: b}
{id: 3, name: c}
{id: 4, name: d}
{id: 5, name: e}
{id: 6, name: f}
```

And I want to group them by 2 in my React component like this :

```
        <div className="group-item">
          <div className="item">a</div>
          <div className="item">b</div>
        </div>
        <div className="group-item">
          <div className="item">c</div>
          <div className="item">d</div>
        </div>
```

etc...

I tried this but I don't know how to conditionally close tags :

```
return _.map(items, (item, i) => {
   let groupStart, groupEnd;
   i % 2 === 0 ? groupStart = <div className="group-item"> : groupEnd = </div>
    return (
        groupStart + item.name + groupEnd
    );
});
```

Would you have some tips to achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593201/reactjs-how-to-render-4-items-in-a-row-items-from-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of conditionally closing tags, you could simply pre-process your data and group it first and then render

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, name: 'a'},
  {id: 2, name: 'b'},
  {id: 3, name: 'c'},
  {id: 4, name: 'd'},
  {id: 5, name: 'e'},
  {id: 6, name: 'f'}
];

const res = data.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  if(index % 2 == 0) {
    acc.push([item])
  } else {
    acc[Math.floor(index/2)].push(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, [])


return _.map(res, (item, i) => {
   return (
     <div className="group-item" key={i}>
         <div>{item[0].name}</div>
         <div>{item[1].name}</div>
     </div>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are already using lodash there is also [_.chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chunk) which you can use to group the items before rendering them:

```
return _.map(_.chunk(items, 2), ([first, second], i) => (
    <div className="group-item" key={i}>
        <div>{first.name}</div>
        <div>{second.name}</div>
    </div>
))
```

[image: Edit ojnk5ow5pz]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. But it is just missing item wrapper. And as per your comment, it should be looped in through a function outside of render hook like:

```
const renderGroupElements = (items) => {
    return _.map(items, (item, i) => {
       let groupStart, groupEnd;
       i % 2 === 0 ? groupStart = <div className="group-item"> : groupEnd = </div>
        return (
            groupStart + <div className="item">{item.name}</div> + groupEnd
        );
    });
}
// And inside the render hook:
{ renderGroupElements(items) }
```

Comment: this is not working, I have an error because of tags in the if statement

Comment: You can't conditionally render closing tags with react/jsx. (And you shouldn't).

Comment: @ZeyukanIch' It's a rendering issue. You can't use such in render hook. Create a new function loop there and it should be fine with `{renderGroupElements(items)}` where this function will now loop through the items.

Comment: I updated my answer in case it was not clear to you.